Kotlin Android different (Module:App) build.gradle structures makes tutorials hard to follow
I am quite new to developing in Android for kotlin.
I was trying to follow a tutorial on how to setup a local Room Database in my App, but my build.gradle looks completely different than the persons gradle in the Tutorial.
My build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.pomodoro28"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.common)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

Build.gradle from the Tutorial:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.plcoding.roomguideandroid'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.roomguideandroid"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    // Room
    def room_version = "2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}

As You can see, his dependencies have a structure like this
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"

While mine look like this
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)

Mine have parentheses, while he has quotation marks.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

His plugins have "id" while mine have alias.
And there are few other syntax/structural differences.
I have basically implemented his Room code 1 : 1, the only difference being my build.gradle, but my app immediately crashes when I launch it, so I believe this is where the error lies.
I asked ChatGpt, but Chat juts told me to straight up copy his into mine.
That did not work.
I tried to simply to a sort of combination of both, like this:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.common)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    def room_version = "2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}

that did also not work.
I have looked at a couple of other Room Tutorials, including the one on the Android Developer site, all of those, seem to follow the structure different to mine. I don't know whats "wrong" with mine or why mine is different than everyone elses (it simply autogenerates when I create an empty project in Android studio). But there seems no immediately obvious fix.

Although both are gradle files, theirs uses Groovy syntax, yours uses Kotlin syntax. You can read more about the migration from Groovy to Kotlin here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html
In addition your gradle setup defines the dependencies in a Version Catalog (a file named libs.versions.toml). For more see this migration guide: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs
The tutorial you use seems to be quite old. In addition to migrating to Kotlin + Version Catalogs you should also update the Room version number from "2.5.0" to "2.6.1" and migrate from kapt to KSP: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

To summarize, for Room you need to add the following to your build files:

libs.versions.toml (merge with the respective sections):
[versions]
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.22" # https://github.com/google/ksp/releases
room = "2.6.1"

[libraries]
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }

[plugins]
google-devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }

Make sure the first part of the ksp version (before the dash) is the same as the Kotlin version you use for your org.jetbrains.kotlin.android plugin. I assumed you used the newest version "2.0.0" (at the time of writing). Always use the newest KSP version compatible to your Kotlin version, you can find all versions here: https://github.com/google/ksp/releases

Top-level build.gradle.kts (merge with the existing plugins block):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp) apply false
}


Module-level build.gradle.kts (merge with the existing blocks):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp)
}

dependencies {
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
}




That said your module-level gradle file already seems to contain this:
implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)

So your version catalog probably also already contains some of what's needed.

Thank you. That was very in depth and helpful and explained everything I had questions about.
I read up on the links you send and was able to fix my app crashing with them.
